# New to Java and have the error "int cannot be dereferenced"

Tags: java

I'm new to java and I've been working on this exercise for a while, but keep receiving the error: int cannot be dereferenced. I saw couple of similar questions but still cannot figure out my own case. 
Here is the complete codes:

```
package inclass;

class OneInt {
  int n;

  OneInt(int n) {
    this.n = n;
  }

  @Override public boolean equals(Object that) {
    if (that instanceof OneInt) {
        OneInt thatInt = (OneInt) that;
        return n.equals(thatInt.n); // error happens here
    } else {
        return false;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object c = new OneInt(9);
    Object c2 = new OneInt(9);
    System.out.println(c.equals(c2));
    System.out.println(c.equals("doesn't work"));
  } 
}
```

Thank you very much for helping me with this little trouble.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`equals` is a method of a class. `int` is a primitive, not a class. Simply use `==` instead:

```
return n == thatInt.n;
```

Answer (score 4):

To compare `int`s, just use the `==` operator:

```
if (n == thatInt.n)
```

Note that `int` is not a class, so you can *never* use the `.` operator with an `int` variable.