# Int Cannot Be Dereferenced In Equals Method

Tags: java, equals

I have an equals method in a Position class. The class contains two instance variables, row and col, that represent the location in a grid. I need to be able to check if two different positions are equal, using an equals method. However, with my current equals method I get an "Int cannot be dereferenced" error upon compiling. I cannot find how to fix this, and the instructor has specified that there should be no reason to overwrite the hashcode. My equals method is below, any help is appreciated.

```
@Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (null == other) return false;
        if (this == other) return true;
        if (!(other instanceof Position)) return false;
        Position that = (Position) other;
        return row.equals(that.getRow()) && col.equals(getCol());
    }
```

EDIT:
row and col are of type int.

Comment: Is `row` an `int`? Or `col`? Primitive types don't have methods.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: that should be an answer.

Comment: If `row` and/or `column` is `int`, then it doesn't have any method at all since it is a primitive type. Change it to `Integer` or use `==` instead.

Comment: Original poster: always tell us clearly which line causes your error. Otherwise you force us to guess -- not good.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15857377/new-to-java-and-have-the-error-int-cannot-be-dereferenced

Comment: Ah! I changed it to == and it works! Thank you I don't know why I didn't realize .equals wouldn't work. If one of you will post that as an answer I will flag as answered.

Comment: The reason why `.equals` didn't work was because it is a method, and `==` is a simple operator. You cannot call methods on primitives, and you were probably trying to do that; you can, however, use the `==` operator on these primitives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `row` and/or `column` is `int`, then it doesn't have any method at all since it is a primitive type. Change it to `Integer` or use `==` instead.